# How to read the response body when API error happen using curl?

Tags: php, api, curl, postman, slim-3

I developed an `API` using `Slim v3`, when an exception is raised I have an `ErrorHandler` which return the following:

```
public function __invoke(Request $request, Response $response, \Exception $exception)
{
    $status = $exception->getCode() ? : 500;
    $error = [
        "status" => ERROR_MSG,
        "data" => [
            "stack_trace" => ($this->_container['settings']['displayErrorDetails']) ? $exception->getTraceAsString() : '',
        ],
        "message" => $exception->getMessage()
    ];

    $body = json_encode($error, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

    return $response
        ->withStatus($status)
        ->withHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
        ->write($body);
}
```

so essentially when an exception happen in the `API` such as:

```
throw new Exception('Invalid user credentials');
```

The `API` will return this response:

```
{
    "status": "error",
    "data": {
        "stack_trace": "some stack trace.."
    },
    "message": "Invalid user credentials"
}
```

now the problem's that when I launch the request using `curl` I only get:

> string(59) "The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error"

from the following code:

```
curl_error($this->session);
```

where `$this->session` contains the request.

I also tried to debug the request using:

```
$this->response = curl_exec($this->session);
$this->info = curl_getinfo($this->session);
$errno = curl_errno($this->session);
$error = curl_error($this->session);
```

and I get:

```
bool(false)
array(26) {
  ["url"]=>
  string(48) "http://localhost/ci3-api/v1/installation/install"
  ["content_type"]=>
  NULL
  ["http_code"]=>
  int(500)
  ["header_size"]=>
  int(0)
  ["request_size"]=>
  int(148)
  ["filetime"]=>
  int(-1)
  ["ssl_verify_result"]=>
  int(0)
  ["redirect_count"]=>
  int(0)
  ["total_time"]=>
  float(0.25)
  ["namelookup_time"]=>
  float(0.016)
  ["connect_time"]=>
  float(0.219)
  ["pretransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.219)
  ["size_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["size_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_download"]=>
  float(0)
  ["speed_upload"]=>
  float(0)
  ["download_content_length"]=>
  float(-1)
  ["upload_content_length"]=>
  float(0)
  ["starttransfer_time"]=>
  float(0.25)
  ["redirect_time"]=>
  float(0)
  ["redirect_url"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["primary_ip"]=>
  string(9) "127.0.0.1"
  ["certinfo"]=>
  array(0) {
  }
  ["primary_port"]=>
  int(80)
  ["local_ip"]=>
  string(9) "127.0.0.1"
  ["local_port"]=>
  int(65036)
}
int(22)
string(59) "The requested URL returned error: 500 Internal Server Error"
```

how can I read the `API` response message? 
Seems impossible to do so when the error `500` is raised from the `API`.
I tried with other error codes such as `400` and I can read the response, but with error code `500` I have the response always `false`.

Comment: It's not immediately obvious from the question, but is `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` true and `var_dump($this->response);` is `bool(false)`?  Also, random suggestions: showing the stack trace and exception message may not be a good idea in case there are any unhandled exceptions that aren't thrown by your code. Additionally, `Invalid user credentials` should be a 401.  You might want to make a special exception that will be recognized by the error handler, and any general exceptions should just return a generic error message, not the exception message.

Comment: The option `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` is setted to true, and the response is always false when an exception happen. I show the stack trace just in the development process, so I can easily debug the request. The exception above, about the credentials, is just an example. So if I understood well, I should return an error code which is not 500 when an exception happen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is my setup; I think important for you is CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER and mainly CURLOPT_FAILONERROR

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'your api url');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false); // this is important for you I think

// other stuff you need to set

$output = curl_exec($ch);

$curlError = curl_error($ch);
$curlErrNo = curl_errno($ch);
$httpCode = (int)curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if($output === false) {
// if header CURLOPT_FAILONERROR is true, always throw here
throw new RuntimeException('curl fail');
}

curl_close($ch);
// here process your output
```

Answer (score 2):

The key is to set `CURLOPT_FAILONERROR` to false. I had the same problem getting the response body from a third-party web service when its http response code was >= 400, and this fixed the problem.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, false);
```